# How to display data from a database in a windows forms solution?

Tags: c#, .net, database, forms

I have a question. How do i display some information from a table in a database in a windows forms solution? Currently I have this code:

```
 private void cafeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dbconn = new DbConnection(MysqlRes.host, MysqlRes.user, MysqlRes.password, MysqlRes.database);
        Query query = new Query(dbconn);
        List<string> cafestring = new List<string>();
        cafestring = query.RunManualQuery("SELECT locationmame FROM location");
        foreach (var cafe in cafestring)
        {
            cafestring.Add(cafe);
        }
```

It just  wont display in my forms solution, where i have a textbox i want this data to be displayed in.. Do any of you guys know how to do this?

Comment: So, you have added the strings to your `cafestring` list - you haven't shown us where you are using this in order to update your UI.

Comment: Why do you instantiate `cafestring` to a new `List<string>` and then immediately reassign it?

Comment: I dont really know.. I am new to C# and i thought this was one way of doing it

Comment: You can just remove `new List<string>()`. That's all I'm saying.